# Adding custom domain to Azure Web App (new portal) won't verify

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have been trying for 3 days now to link custom domains, `caretopets.com` and `www.caretopets.com`, to an Azure Web app - the issue is that I am was not able to verify it (I get both Domain ownership and Hostname availability errors).

The domain is newly purchased from godaddy. I read several articles, and also have other web app with different domain linked.  I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.

I added the required `A`, `TXT` and CNAME records as seen here:

[image: GoDaddy Records]

I checked the records with digwebinterface:

[image: DigiWeb Results]

The only thing is that there are some strange additional `CNAME`s.

I also tried to verify a domain that is already linked to another web app in the same subscription, and even that one won't verify as well.

Any suggestions on where to go from here would be helpful.

Comment: whats the error message, how long ago did you add them?

Comment: Could you embed the .png files in your post instead of providing links to them, please?

Comment: you can edit the post @feedMe

Comment: It just say "Error",  no other explanatory message, for both the domain ownership and hostname availability.

Answer (score 0):

> link a custom domain caretopets.com and www.caretopets.com to an Azure Web app I am was not able to verify it

To map custom domain to web app, I create the DNS record(s) like this. I could validate Domain successfully.

[image]

As far as I know, it should report success or detailed error with prescriptive guidence on how to fix the error while checking for Domain ownership and Hostname availability in Azure portal.

[image]

Please make sure whether you point to correct IP address and Azure app's default domain name.

Besides, [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-custom-domain-name#verify-dns-propagation) shows us how to manually map a custom domain name to web app with detailed steps, please refer to it.